# How to control a class of 4 year old children?

Tags: school, bilingual, teacher

Any advice on how to "manage", "gain control" and get the "attention" from a class of 4 yr olds? This was not covered in my University course.

Note: English is their second language, and I must only speak English to them.

Answer (score 7):

Sergio and Dave BOTH have good answers for general activities, but if you are simply looking for a signal to get them to quite down and look at you for transitioning to the next activity there are a number of things to try depending on the specifics of the situation.  You have to teach them it will be a signal and then use it pretty often first, but there are a number of things teachers, camp counselors, parents with large broods, etc. use for this.  Again, most of these have to be taught first, especially with a group that doesn't speak english, but they are quick, simple classroom management tools to get the kids ready to listen or watch for your next instructions.

I used to use all of these:

- Sing a popular jingle, but only the first half - for example the
  MacDonald's Da,da,da, da da.  Wait for them to follow with "I'm
  lovin' it."   The point here is to choose something with which almost
  everyone will be familiar.
- Clap a rythm and expect them to repeat it.
- Flip the light switch off and then on again twice.
- Whisper, "If you can hear me clap twice."  Then follow that
  with, "If you can hear me clap three times. . .  and so on.  when
  you have everyone's attention, congratulate them, you only had
  to clap *_* times this time.  Lets see if it can be less next
  time!
- Use a song you can play on your musical player (whether it be a CD, Ipod . . . ) that is a motion song like "Jim along Josie" or "I Had a Little Bicycle."  They do the motions and when the song is over, sit down listening ready.
- Have a picture of what they should look like to be "ready" for the next activity that you simply stand and point to until most or all of them are in the "ready" position.
- Put up one hand in the air and the other in the "shh" symbol by your lips and wait quietly - many kids will have experienced this in other environments (yes, even at age four and in other cultures) and will simply copy you.

For an idea that will only work once or twice - but requires no "training time" do something completely silly and random like Moo loudly (my favorite was to bray like a donkey).  They'll giggle a lot, but you'll have their attention.  You'll only have them for a few split seconds right afterward, but you will have their attention - now you just have to keep their attention.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 4):

Some loose suggestions:

- make sports or let them play in the playground. If they are physically tired they will be more calm in the class room.
- make it fun, find out what they like & let them take part in decisions but still be very keen of who takes the last decision.
- use their hands. 4 year olds like to create, let them use their hands to paint, build lego or some other constructive activity and include what you want to teach in the games/paining.
- read stories for them, stopping sometimes to ask them what will happen and create suspense.
- sing! Children love to sing. Keep in mind children sing in a higher pitch than adults, so try to sing in their pitch or let them take the tone.
- simulate their life outside school. Make up games recreating moments from their life. A restaurant (giving different roles to them), a bus trip, train describing the landscape, food store etc. They know that situation and by simulating it they can change it with the imagination and have fun.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Sergio's answer:

- Have frequent breaks. A four year old's concentration span is very limited.
- Read the situation, if the kids are getting bored then change your approach.
- Incorporate movement between lessons.
- Kids who have trouble concentrating should be at the front of the class so you can engage them.
- Try to keep the class quiet when they need to concentrate, it is easy to overload a young mind.

This is based upon the experience of my lad who started school at 4.5 and his noob teacher. She'd try to make them concentrate for 30~45 minutes at a time. This was not possible, even for the older kids. She reads books so slowly that the kids get bored.

Many kids (like our boy) crave movement and exercise - he needs it in order to concentrate. We've taught him to do things like chair push-ups if he has trouble concentrating. This can be incorporated into the day. For birthday parties, we'll get the kids to do some light exercise before the entertainment comes on; it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Praise and ignore, praise and ignore, praise and ignore.  Works miracles with everyone from young children to full adults.  Despite my ardent belief in this, I am still shocked every time it works.  "Thank you Beth for sitting quietly and listening!  I see Ronnie is quiet and ready to learn; great job Ronnie!"  They'll fall in line.

(Seriously, this is how I get my partner to do the dishes and other household chores.  Please don't tell him.)